# Как по нажатию на кнопку изменить одну картинку на другую?

Tags: изображения, button, flutter, dart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я новичок, и еще не совсем понимаю как работать с состояниями виджетов.
есть **2 кнопки** и при нажатии на одну из них должна **меняться картинка над ними**. А при нажатии на **3 кнопку "Сбросить"** картинка сверху должна **вернуться в исходное состояние.**
пока нет идей как это сделать, либо условие прописать if(){}, либо Switcher какой-то использовать для переключения.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextUp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextUp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
        Image.asset("assets/images/Снимок экрана 2023-06-16 в 18.40.42.png",
            width: 300);
// Image.asset("assets/images/Снимок экрана 2023-06-16 в 18.31.10.png",
//         width: 300);
//эту картинку нужно показать вместо старой и по нажатию на 3 кнопку она уходит и снова появляется 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: работа примера]

```
// вся логика в этом классе
class HomeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  HomeNotifier();

  // флаг для первой картинки
  bool _firstImageState = false;
  bool get firstImageState => _firstImageState;

  // флаг для второй картинки
  bool _secondImageState = false;
  bool get secondImageState => _secondImageState;

  // изменение флага первой картинки
  void changeFirstImageState() {
    if (_firstImageState) {
      return;
    }
    _firstImageState = true;
    // оповещение об изменении
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // изменение флага второй картинки
  void changeSecondImageState() {
    if (_secondImageState) {
      return;
    }
    _secondImageState = true;
    // оповещение об изменении
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // сброс флагов картинок
  void reset() {
    _firstImageState = false;
    _secondImageState = false;
    // оповещение об изменении
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
// спец. вариант InheritedWidget
class HomeInheritedNotifier extends InheritedNotifier<HomeNotifier> {
  const HomeInheritedNotifier(
      {super.key, required super.notifier, required super.child});

  static HomeNotifier _notifierOf(BuildContext context, [bool depend = true]) {
    if (depend) {
      return context
          .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<HomeInheritedNotifier>()!
          .notifier!;
    } else {
      return context
          .getInheritedWidgetOfExactType<HomeInheritedNotifier>()!
          .notifier!;
    }
  }

  static bool firstImageStateOf(BuildContext context) =>
      _notifierOf(context).firstImageState;

  static bool secondImageStateOf(BuildContext context) =>
      _notifierOf(context).secondImageState;

  static VoidCallback changeFirstOf(BuildContext context) =>
      _notifierOf(context, false).changeFirstImageState;

  static VoidCallback changeSecondOf(BuildContext context) =>
      _notifierOf(context, false).changeSecondImageState;

  static VoidCallback resetOf(BuildContext context) =>
      _notifierOf(context, false).reset;
}
```

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: HomeInheritedNotifier(
        notifier: HomeNotifier(),
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: HomeInheritedNotifier.changeFirstOf(context),
                  child: HomeInheritedNotifier.firstImageStateOf(context)
                      ? Image.asset('assets/happy.png')
                      : Image.asset('assets/bored.png'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: HomeInheritedNotifier.changeSecondOf(context),
                  child: HomeInheritedNotifier.secondImageStateOf(context)
                      ? Image.asset('assets/smile.png')
                      : Image.asset('assets/neutral.png'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: HomeInheritedNotifier.resetOf(context),
                child: Text('Сбросить')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Второй возможный вариант без использования `InheritedNotifier`, но использованием `ListenableBuilder`

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: HomePage(
        notifier: HomeNotifier(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key, required this.notifier});

  final HomeNotifier notifier;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: notifier.changeFirstImageState,
                    child: ListenableBuilder(
                      listenable: notifier,
                      builder: (context, child) => notifier.firstImageState
                          ? Image.asset('assets/happy.png')
                          : Image.asset('assets/bored.png'),
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: notifier.changeSecondImageState,
                  child: ListenableBuilder(
                    listenable: notifier,
                    builder: (context, child) => notifier.secondImageState
                        ? Image.asset('assets/smile.png')
                        : Image.asset('assets/neutral.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: notifier.reset,
              child: Text('Сбросить'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```